In "Blood Meridian", why does the gang so fiercely disagree with the specifics of the Judge's story about the harnessmaker?
In Blood Meridian by Cormac McCarthy, after the Judge tells his story about the harnessmaker that killed the traveler, the gang all start objecting to different aspects of the story:

Here the judge looked up and smiled. There was a silence, then all began to shout at once with every kind of disclaimer.
He was no harnessmaker he was a shoemaker and he was cleared of them charges, called one.
And another: He never lived in no wilderness place, he had a shop dead in the center of Cumberland Maryland.
They never knew where them bones come from. The old woman was crazy, known to be so.
That was my brother in that casket and he was a minstrel dancer out of Cincinnati Ohio was shot to death over a woman.
And other protests until the judge raised both hands for silence.

I understand there are some deep thematic aspects of the tale itself, and it would have to be a fictional morality play since the Judge divulged details about the murder that nobody could have known (or a supernatural insight from the Judge). But I can't figure out why the gang took issue with different parts like they personally knew the players or why these specific issues are brought up or why half of them don't make sense.
The harnessmaker in the story couldn't have been cleared of charges since the Judge took great pains to explain that nobody was witness to the crime so there'd be nobody to bring charges. The story also requires that the harnessmaker lived in the wilderness in order to commit the murder and run his begging racket, so he couldn't have lived in the middle of town. And the description of the funeral hearse driver wouldn't be enough for the gang member to know that it was his brother being driven around.
The fact that McCarthy explicitly doesn't detail who said which complaint means this isn't meant to inform specific gang members' backgrounds or insights. That much I get. But aside from that this doesn't make any sense to me, either in a metaphorical or realistic sense.
